# Not a regular file, you need to load the kernel first - mkusb

Tags: grub, live-usb, persistence, clone

I'm using mkusb to make an install of TinyCoreLinuxPlus.  I used mkusb-dus, selected the option for a persistent live drive, chose my coreplus.iso file, and cloned to the drive as usual.  However, when I restart, I am met with a light-gray grub menu, and whichever option I choose I get the error "not a regular file - need to load the kernel first."  This is strange, because I previously used Etcher to make a live Xubuntu and Linux Mint install and it booted just fine; other answers suggested to me claim that Secure Boot is affecting this, but according to [this support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208862) my MacBook Pro mid-2015 15-inch doesn't have secure boot.  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: mkusb can be used to *clone* from a Tiny Core iso file to a USB pendrive, and a working live system will be created. But the methods in mkusb for persistent live drives are only working for Ubuntu and Debian and some distros derived from them. Tiny Core has its own method to remember things between reboots, and I *think* they can be activated from a cloned system.

Comment: See this link: [Frugal Install Tiny Core Linux](http://tinycorelinux.net/install.html) - Tiny Core's installer is also applicable to USB sticks and other external media.

Comment: @sudodus thanks for the clarification on mkusb!  I thought mkusb was a flashing program like etcher T-T

Comment: It depends what you mean by a flashing program. Some people use cloning and flashing to describe the same operation (in our case to copy every bit without modification from a file to a device). --To me flashing simply means writing to a flash drive and mkusb is such a program. It can do some of all the possible kinds of flashing operations: cloning of iso files and extraction+cloning of gzip- and xz-compressed image files plus more specific configuration and extraction to create persistent live Ubuntu and Debian systems.

Comment: Cloning works with most Linux iso files: The target USB drive will be bootable. In addition to cloning mkusb can make persistent live Xubuntu and Linux Mint systems, to mention the two distros you referred to in the original question. But in most cases people make 'plain' live (live-only) drives by cloning, also when they use mkusb where it would be possible to make persistent live drives, simply because they do not need persistence, and a live-only drive is snappier and more robust than a persistent live drive.